# R Shiny error: EXPR must be a length 1 vector

Tags: r, shiny, wavelet, wavelet-transform

I'm working on the same program which has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206529/r-shiny-error-argument-x-is-missing-with-no-default) but with some modifications in the server code. Here is its updated version:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  dataset<-reactive({ 
    inFile <- input$filewav 
    dat <- read_excel(inFile$datapath)
    df <- data.frame(dat[,2], dat[,3])
    x <- seq(1,nrow(df),length = nrow(df))
    y <- df[,2]
    return(dat)
  })

  output$plot_mra <- renderPlot({
    filt <- switch(input$filterwav, 
            "Haar (d2)" = ls()[5],
            "d4" = ls()[7],
            "d6" = ls()[9],
            "d8" = ls()[11],
            "s4" = ls()[13],
            "s6" = ls()[15],
            "s8" = ls()[17],
            "c6" = ls()[3],
            "c12" = ls()[1])
    set.seed(2)
    inFile <- input$filewav 
    dat <- read_excel(inFile$datapath)
    df <- data.frame(dat[,2], dat[,3])
    x <- seq(1,nrow(df),length = nrow(df))
    y <- df[,2]
    y.mra <- mra(y,filt,input$reswav,"periodic",TRUE,"modwt")
    if(input$reswav==0)
        {plot(x,y, ylab = "", type = "p", col = "red")
        mtext("Fungsi Asli", side = 3, line = 0.1)}
    else
        mra.y <- switch(input$reswav, 
                 "1" = y.mra()@S$S1,
                 "2" = y.mra()@S$S2,
                 "3" = y.mra()@S$S3,
                 "4" = y.mra()@S$S4,
                 "5" = y.mra()@S$S5,
                 "6" = y.mra()@S$S6,
                 "7" = y.mra()@S$S7,
                 "8" = y.mra()@S$S8,
                 "9" = y.mra()@S$S9,
                 "10" = y.mra()@S$S10)
    {plot(x,y, ylab = "", type = "p", col = "red")
    par(new = TRUE)
    plot(x,mra.y, ylab = "y", xlab = "x", type = "l", col = "blue")
    mtext("Hasil Analisis Multiresolusi dengan MODWT", side = 3, line = 0.1)}
})
}
```

I tried to execute those codes along with the UI code from aforementioned link with `shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)` and this time I got this error in the R console:

```
Warning: Error in switch: EXPR must be a length 1 vector
Stack trace (innermost first):
    105: excel_format
    104: read_excel_
    103: read_excel
    102: renderPlot [#25]
     92: <reactive:plotObj>
     81: plotObj
     80: origRenderFunc
     79: output$plot_mra
      4: <Anonymous>
      3: do.call
      2: print.shiny.appobj
      1: <Promise>
```

Any ideas where I might have gone wrong? And how am I supposed to fix it?

Update: Okay, I've edited my server code according to Gregor de Cillia's suggestion. Here is its updated version:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  dataset<-reactive({ 
    inFile <- input$filewav 
    dat <- read_excel(inFile$datapath)
    df <- data.frame(dat[,2], dat[,3])
    x <- seq(1,nrow(df),length = nrow(df))
    y <- df[,2]
    return(dat)
  })

  output$plot_mra <- renderPlot({
    read_excel(req(input$filewav))
    filt <- switch(input$filterwav, 
            "Haar (d2)" = ls()[5],
            "d4" = ls()[7],
            "d6" = ls()[9],
            "d8" = ls()[11],
            "s4" = ls()[13],
            "s6" = ls()[15],
            "s8" = ls()[17],
            "c6" = ls()[3],
            "c12" = ls()[1])
    set.seed(2)
    inFile <- input$filewav 
    dat <- read_excel(inFile$datapath)
    df <- data.frame(dat[,2], dat[,3])
    x <- seq(1,nrow(df),length = nrow(df))
    y <- df[,2]
    y.mra <- mra(y,filt,input$reswav,"periodic",TRUE,"modwt")
    if(input$reswav==0)
        {plot(x,y, ylab = "", type = "p", col = "red")
        mtext("Fungsi Asli", side = 3, line = 0.1)}
    else
        mra.y <- switch(input$reswav, 
                 "1" = y.mra()@S$S1,
                 "2" = y.mra()@S$S2,
                 "3" = y.mra()@S$S3,
                 "4" = y.mra()@S$S4,
                 "5" = y.mra()@S$S5,
                 "6" = y.mra()@S$S6,
                 "7" = y.mra()@S$S7,
                 "8" = y.mra()@S$S8,
                 "9" = y.mra()@S$S9,
                 "10" = y.mra()@S$S10)
    {plot(x,y, ylab = "", type = "p", col = "red")
    par(new = TRUE)
    plot(x,mra.y, ylab = "y", xlab = "x", type = "l", col = "blue")
    mtext("Hasil Analisis Multiresolusi dengan MODWT", side = 3, line = 0.1)}
})
}
```

There seems to be no problems in the program at first ([basically like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2q5Km.jpg)), but the problem persists right after I upload an *.xls or *.xlsx file ([as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwbpp.jpg)). Also, when I try to troubleshoot it with `traceback()`, R's only response is `No traceback available`.

PS: again, please excuse my language, I'm using Bahasa Indonesia in my program above.

Comment: You have nor provided your `ui` and we don't know what is `input$reswav`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I've already provided a link for that one. In case you skipped it, [here's the link that I'm talking about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206529/r-shiny-error-argument-x-is-missing-with-no-default).

Comment: Try using `read_excel(req(inFile$datapath))` in your `renderPlot.`

Comment: @GregordeCillia noted. Please have a look at my updated question above.